# jQUERY Star-Rating not working

Tags: jquery

Currently I try to add the following star rating plugin to my wordpress blog: [FYNEWORKS](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing)

But for some reason i doesn't seem to work. I am totally new to jQuery so hope you can help me out.

Added to the HEADER:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/jquery.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/jquery.rating.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/jquery.form.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/jquery.MetaData.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/jquery.rating.pack.js"/>
```

And also in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    ('.hover-star').rating({ 
        focus: function(value, link){ 
            var tip = $('#hover-test'); 
            tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html(); 
            tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value); 
        }, 
        blur: function(value, link){ 
            var tip = $('#hover-test'); 
            $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || ''); 
        } 
     });
});
</script>
```

My CSS File:

```
/* jQuery.Rating Plugin CSS - http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ */
div.rating-cancel,div.star-rating{float:left;width:17px;height:15px;text-indent:-999em;cursor:pointer;display:block;background:transparent;overflow:hidden;}
div.rating-cancel,div.rating-cancel a{background:url("/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/delete.gif") no-repeat 0 -16px; !important}
div.star,div.star a{background:url("/wp-content/themes/wordpress-naked/js/star.gif") no-repeat 0 0px; !important}
div.rating-cancel a,div.star-rating a{display:block;width:16px;height:100%;background-position:0 0px;border:0 !important;}
div.star-rating-on a{background-position:0 -16px!important;}
div.star-rating-hover a{background-position:0 -32px;}
/* Read Only CSS */
div.star-rating-readonly a{cursor:default !important;}
/* Partial Star CSS */
div.star-rating{background:transparent!important;overflow:hidden!important;}
/* END jQuery.Rating Plugin CSS */
```

My Radio Buttons have the class as defined in the second code part ".hover-star.

However, it is still not working. Did i make a typo or am i overlooking something?

Thnx :)

Comment: try adding `$` here `$('.hover-star').rating({`

Answer (score 0):

Your script should almost always start after the document has fully been loaded, otherwise it is executed too early and the items won't be found.

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... // your code // ... })
```

*wirey* is correct too about the missing $

Comment: Oops didn't know that myself :(

Comment: Now you do :)  It's just a shorthand/shortcut version

Comment: Not sure if it is allowed, but this is the page i'm talking about:
http://beebo.nl/test123-2/

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are not calling jQuery here:

`('.hover-star').rating({`

You need call jQuery with `$` or `jQuery`:

`$('.hover-star').rating({`

There might be other issues too.  I would suggest using a debugger.  It would have helped find this issue and others.

Comment: Added the $ sign so jquery will call it. No luck so far, But i really appreciate the fast replies :)